# HTTP post request returns HTML error instead of returning Java Object

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, ajax

Here is the controller for my code for which I am making AJAX request:

Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/tools/searchConfigurations", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody ProductConfiguration searchConfigurations(@RequestParam String productNumber,
        @RequestParam String productName, @RequestParam String productType, HttpServletResponse response) {

    try {
        // I am setting values here 


        return productConfiguration.build();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        final String errorMsg = "Encountered error when viewing " +
                "product configurations. Exception: " + e.getMessage() +
                ExceptionUtils.getStackTrace(e);

        logger.error(errorMsg);
        return null;
    }
}
```

Here is the AJAX call to the controller.

AJAX Call:

JavaScript:

```
$("#searchConfigurationsBtn").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({type: "POST",
            url: "/tools/searchConfigurations",
            data: { productName: $("#productName").val(),
            productType: $("#productType").val(),
            productNumber: $("#productNumber").val()},
            success: function(result) {
                $("#searchConfigurationsResponse").show();
            },
            error: function(result) {
                console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
            }                
    });
});
```

Here is the HTML/JSP file which fetches the parameters for controller.

JSP:

```
        <form id="searchConfigurationsForm" role="form" autocomplete="off">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="productName">Brand Name:</label> 
                    <input type="text"
                        class="form-control" id="productName"
                        placeholder="Enter brand name"
                        name="productName">
                <label for="productType">TYPE:</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="productType"
                        placeholder="TYPE" name="productType"> 
                <label for="productNumber">UPC of Item:</label> 
                    <input type="text"
                        class="form-control" id="productNumber" placeholder="Number of Item"
                        name="productNumber">
            </div>
            <div class="button">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-large btn-primary"
                    id="searchConfigurationsBtn">Search</button>
            </div>

            <div id="searchConfigurationsResponse" style="display: none;">
                <jsp:include page="/WEB-INF/views/configurations/viewconfigurations.jsp" />
            </div>
        </form>
```

Here is the Stringified message in AJAX call error handler:

{"readyState":4,"responseText":"Error report

## HTTP Status 500 -

**type** Status report

**message**

**description** The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

","status":500,"statusText":"Internal Server Error"}

I am expecting 'ProductConfigurations' object to be returned but the Ajax request errors out.

I have Jackson-mapper -  1.9 already on my class path.

Comment: Are there any errors in your server logs?

Comment: no logs on the server, everything looks fine.